# On click for bitmap image in canvas in android

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

How to make the bitmap image clickable on canvas in android like a button on click listener?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set click listeners directly on a Canvas. If your bitmap is being set to an ImageView, you can just set a click listener on it as normal:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    //do something
})
```

Otherwise, you can create a custom `View` and use your `Canvas` in its `onDraw()` method. You can then use the `onTouch()` method to capture click events.

Comment: Thank u.  How to create a  movable custom view inside a canvas ?

Comment: If you have another question it would be best to post another question with the code you've tried.